# Blank space appearing at bottom of all webpages in Google Chrome on iOS

Tags: ios, google-chrome

I noticed recently that every webpage I visit on iOS Chrome has an enormous blank space at the bottom of the page. The space is roughly equal to a full screen height (i.e. 100vh) and is located below all visible elements on the page. Basically I can keep scrolling the page until it's completely blank. The scrollbar also shows that the pages are much longer than their content would require.

All the pages I looked at behave fine on Android, on OSX, and even on iOS when I use Firefox or Safari. The issue seems specific to iOS Chrome. I'm not sure when this issue started but I've updated Chrome and it persists.

Is anyone else experiencing this iOS Chrome bug? I haven't found any info about it.

I created a dummy test webpage and just kept stripping it down to see what was causing the issue. Eventually I was left with a page containing only `<p>` tags and very minimal CSS (no positioning properties) but the extra space at page bottom still showed up. By adding a background-color to the `<body>` I could see that this extra space was within the `<body>` but there wasn't any element forcing the body to extend.

After much trial and error I discovered that if I disable Chrome's Smooth Scrolling this issue is resolved and all pages behave normally.
Solution: Load `chrome://flags` and set Smooth Scrolling to disable.

Seems odd that this would be necessary. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Thank you for your question, because that happenned to me today and I started to go crazy before I stumbled upon your post

Answer (score 3):

This is likely a Chrome bug (iPad). I also spent a lot of time debugging all the css and my components. End up event google.com it self has that mysterious white space (which is about the height of the content itself.).

6 hours gone, but it's a relieve to know it's nothing got to do with my codes.

iPhone with chrome is fine on my end

[image: iPad Chrome]

Comment: Yes this exactly what I'm seeing. I haven't tested on iphone, only ipad. Interesting that Chrome on iphone wouldn't show this bug. Do you have the same version of iOS and Chrome on both devices?

Comment: they 2 apps are different because they are design independently to the device

Comment: I'm seeing this on every website using Chrome on iPhone 11

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial but don't Safari iPhone and Safari iPad both use the same rendering engine? 
My understanding is that Apple even forces Mozilla and Google to also use the Safari rendering engine on iOS, which is one reason why it's seemingly impossible to target CSS to different browser on iOS. But those iOS browsers do all exhibit slightly different rendering bugs. It's like iOS is the new IE. Browsers on android are a dream in comparison

Comment: Well presuming they are, I still don't see the same gap on iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the page from scrolling, in both x, and y axis, we use the overflow: hidden; attribute in css.

So if we apply this to the body,

```
body {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

this should work in your scenario!

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, the blank space appears in ALL webpages I view in iOS Chrome (i.e. on ALL websites), not just on my page. The page I created was strictly for testing purposes AFTER I had noticed this issue. Are you suggesting that I add body overflow:hidden to every page on the internet?

Comment: ... but I did visit websites with body overflow set to hidden, so I can confirm that this doesn't hide the blank space.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have added this meta tag and the same attributes

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
```

And check your body tag CSS, there should not be height: 100vh and check your pages again by clearing browser cache or in the private mode.

Comment: I'm using that meta tag and no height on body. 
As I mentioned in my post, the blank space appears in ALL webpages I view in iOS Chrome (i.e. on ALL websites), not just on my page. The page I created was strictly for testing purposes AFTER I had noticed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling smooth scrolling took care of this problem on my iPhone 14 Pro on iOS 17.2.1.

Comment: Are you saying thanks for one of the existing answers or comments? Or do you mean this to be an answer according to [answer]. In that case please [edit] to make that more obvious.

Comment: It appears that the OP edited in the answer, so IMHO, this could be edited into a proper Answer.